# Installing Windows 8 from a Hard Drive forces it to be a dependend drive to load Windows

Tags: installation, boot, mbr, windows-8, bcd

I wanted to do a clean install of Windows 8 using a hard drive as an installation medium to a clean separate hard drive.

Here is an initial hard drive config:

A Windows 7 (I boot from it by default) 1.5 TB drive. A 320GB installation medium drive and a 2TB destination drive.

I booted into Windows 7 and have foramted the 320GB drive using the instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/habibh/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-flash-drive-to-install-windows-8-developer-preview).

The have switched in BIOS to load from a newly formated 320GB drive. An installation went fine.

I have chosen to install Windows on a 2TB drive. After installation was finished, the system has booted from a 320GB drive, but into a Windows 8 that was on 2TB drive as expected.

Now my idea was that I mark a 2TB drive as an active drive, tell BIOS to load from it and I will be getting a Windows 8 load by default. But that is not the case. The only way I can load my computer is when I have an installtion 320GB drive attached. Without it I get a BCD error. How can I transfer MBR to 2TB drive to be able to load from it without 320GB drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disconnect 320gig drive, boot from a W8 install disc, load windows RE, then [run this command from the command prompt](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392)

> bootrec /RebuildBcd

Comment: That is the thing - I don't have a DVD-drive, that's why I wanted to do it all with HD. I will wait a day, maybe someone will post a hint on a DVD-free solution. If not, I will mark that one as an answer.

Comment: You can convert the DVD to a usb drive, boot from that.

Comment: My 320gig drive is exactly that. And what it did was install MBR onto itself, and now I can't boot without it.

Comment: You need to boot from a different usb drive, then run the commands, be sure the 320 is not connected when you do this.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but the suggestion below should work. I am not saying it is elegant, just that it should work. I have copied it directly from [here](http://beyondteck.blogspot.fr/2010/10/reinstall-windows-7-bootloader-without.html).

**DISCLAMER: This is not a nice way to treat your hardware.**

> 1. Make sure you back up your computer. I've tried this procedure with Windows 7 Professional, but I'm not sure if it'll work on your version
>      of Windows 7.
> 2. Start your computer and boot into Windows 7 (has to be Windows 7! This won't work with any previous versions as far as I know, may work
>      with Vista, but I've never tried it.)
> 3. While Windows is booting, turn off your computer! That's right... hold down your power button for a few seconds and abruptly turn off
>      your computer
> 4. Turn on your computer again, and boot into Windows.
> 5. Windows should give you a message telling you that it did not start up properly... it should give you two options: "Launch startup repair"
>      or Start windows normally... Select Launch Startup Repair
> 6. Now let Windows try to find problems. It most likely won't realize that what you're trying to do is restore the windows bootloader. Once
>      it's done, it'll ask you if you want to restore your system using
>      System Restore. You probably don't want this, so hit cancel on the
>      Window and let windows "attempt repairs" (this doesn't do anything
>      really... just tries to find things that are wrong with your copies of
>      windows and nothing more).
> 7. Windows should then give you a message that start up repair cannot repair the computer automatically. Simply close the window, and click
>      "View advanced options for system recovery"  on the window behind the
>      one you just closed. It should ask you for the keyboard layout, and
>      your admin password.

Then follow the [instructions on this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392) (essentially use the  Bootrec.exe /FixMbr command), and use the command prompt window.

The linked page, and actual solution, are the same as in @Moab's answer below. This trick should just get you to the point where you can apply it.